# Store a csv file created by a python script on Hudson

Tags: python, csv, jenkins, hudson, store

I have a python script that creates a csv file and I have a Hudson job that builds every day. I want to store the csv file as an artifact but when I start the job nothing is stored or created. The build is successful and all tests are done but no file is created. 
Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the windows command line to execute the python script and it worked.